# How to create a persistent database connection in NextJS

Tags: javascript, database, next.js

I'm creating a messaging app with NextJS using SQLite as my database. I noticed that you can "prepare" statements in SQLite which can make it more efficient.

I have a `dbHelper.js` which I import into each API handler and take it from there. e.g.

```
// lib/dbHelper.js
import Database from "better-sqlite3";

const db = new Database("./data/thedata.db");

const getMessagesStatement = db.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM messages LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"
);
function getMessages(fromIdx = 0, maxResults = 100) {
    return getMessagesStatement.all(parseInt(maxResults), parseInt(fromIdx));
}
```

```
// pages/api/getMessages.js
import { getMessages } from "../../lib/dbHelper";

export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send(getMessages(req.query.fromIdx, req.query.maxResults));
}
```

However, doing it this way means dbHelper isn't persistent and `getMessagesStatement` is re-prepared each time an API handler is called. Furthermore, `db` gets opened and closed with each API call also. I assume this invalidates any performance improvements from using "prepare".

How do I keep this database connection open?

I've looked at other posts and blog sites but all of them point to just opening and closing the connection each time a handler is called. Is this the only way to go?

Comment: Hi Zacoons! Check out the linked thread's answer and let me know whether it solves your issue or not. If it doesn't, we will reopen it :)